# Is it possible to create a Class in React that can still access the global Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I would like to create a class like such

```
class Person {
  constructor(fname, lname) {
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
  }
}
```

so that I can use it normally like:

```
let temp = new Person('John', 'Doe');
```

but is there any way I can have that class access the global store?

I would love to do something like:

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.fname = this.props.fname;
    this.lname = this.props.lname;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    fname: state.person.fname,
    lname: state.person.lname
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Person);
```

but because the constructor for a React Component seems to be

```
constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
}
```

i figured it might not be possible?  but i wanted to ask anyway as it would help alot.  Thanks

Comment: What would `this.props` be inside a `new Person`?

Comment: @Bergi well if i can connect to the Redux store using mapStateToProps, then the fname and lname variables will be added to my local props.  added the "connect" line so that hopefully it's more clear what i'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal classes won't go through the same types of lifecycle as a react component, so `connect` won't make sense here.

Additionally, you really want to avoid storing the same state in multiple places. The whole point of redux is to consolidate state, and manage it for you. So I would recommend that you instead call `store.getState()` in any method that would need to know the current `fname` `lname` instead of trying to manange synchronization between redux state and `this.fname`,`this.lname`

To do this, you will have to expose the current `store` through some sort of `import`, which you may already be doing.

If you are not yet doing this, I recommend using the following syntax

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export let store = null; // placeholder for store singleton once created

export function init(initialState = {}){
   store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
   return store;
}
```

then from your person class you can simply

```
import { store } from '../store';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    fname: state.person.fname,
    lname: state.person.lname
  };
}

export default class Person() {
    constructor(){
    }

    toString() {
        // example method 
        let { fname, lname } = mapStateToProps(store.getState());
        return `${fname} ${lname}`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `connect` won't work for plain classes like that.  It only works for React components, since it access the store via props or context, and accepts/uses React components.

You'd need to access the store object directly, via an import.  There *are* a number of other utilities that help manage the store subscription process as well - perhaps one of them might help you.  See my list at [Redux addons catalog: Store - Store Change Subscriptions](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store.md#store-change-subscriptions).

That said, ultimately all those really do is call `store.subscribe()` at some point, and do something with `store.getState()` in their subscription callbacks.